# Batching and Uploaded real-time traffic to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, real-time, batch-processing, bigdata

I am looking for some suggestion/solutions on implementing a archiving work flow at at big data scale.
The source of data are messages in kafka. Which is written to in real-time. Destination is S3 bucket.
I need to partition the data based on a field in message. For each partition i need to batch data to 100Mb chunks and then upload it. 
The data rate is ~5GB/Minute. So the 100Mb batch should get filled within couple of seconds.

My trouble is around scaling and batching. Since i need to batch and compression data for a "field" in message, i need to bring that part of data together by partitioning. Any suggestions on tech/work flow ?

Comment: Look into Kinesis Firehose, which takes readings and puts them in S3. No ordering guarantees, you need to arrange re-sending of a small percentage of failures (0.01~0.1% on average), but quick and easy.

Comment: I need very strict data guarantees on data loss. Data loss is not acceptable. Ordering guarantee is not needed

Comment: No data loss with the S3 connector for Kafka. You can also put in whatever batch policy you want. Scaling a connector is also trivial. http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/s3_connector.html

Comment: Confluent Kafka Sink Connector for S3 guarantees no data loss and exactly once delivery (no duplicates) in S3 even if there are network or process failures.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Kafka Connect. There's a connector for S3:

http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/s3_connector.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apache spark to do scaling and batching processes for you. So basically the flow can look like this:

Apache Kafka -> Apache Spark -> Amazon S3.

Spark Streaming API enables scalable, high-throughput, fault-tolerant stream processing of live data streams. Data can be ingested from many sources like Kafka and can be processed using complex algorithms such as high-level functions like map, reduce, join and window. Finally, processed data can be pushed out to filesystems like Amazon S3.